# If a question comes up that is off topic, but already has a good answer - do we migrate it?

Tags: discussion

Typically general Photoshop questions are off topic here and we migrate to either SU or GFX - but what if [its already received a valid answe](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/13116/apply-an-overlay-layer-to-a-single-layer-and-then-adjust-the-result-of-that)r.  Do we let sleeping dogs lie or move it because it will be easier for other folks to find it in the 'right' place in the future?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the question is strongly off-topic it should be migrated.

Don't worry -- a great answer remains a great answer, whether it is here or on another Stack Exchange site!

Answer (score 2):

I believe that if a question is off topic, then it is off topic, and should be open to migration (where a migration path exists) or closure if off topic across the StackExchange network.

There have been occasions on various Stack Exchange sites where I've known the answer, but also recognise that it's off topic; what I would typically do and advocate would be to "vote to close as off topic, belongs on [other site]" and then answer it, happy in the knowledge that my answer will fly across with it to the other site.